# Editar arquivo da impressora Zebra ".lbl" Java

Tags: java, arquivo, edittext, impressora

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte, tenho um sistema aonde o usuário vai fazer o upload de uma etiqueta padrão, feita no Zebra Designer (ex: `etiqueta.lbl`), para seu produtos e de acordo com o produto que ele for imprimir a etiqueta, na impressora Zebra, nela vai ter que ser gerado um código de barras com algumas informações do produto, para isso usei a biblioteca Barbecue para código de barras, mas preciso editar a etiqueta para conseguir inserir o mesmo.

Realizei alguns testes editando textos fixos na etiqueta pelo próprio `Notepad++,` aonde é possível reconhecer algumas palavras, e quando editado por lá, se a palavra nova for do mesmo tamanho da antiga, não há erro ao abrir o arquivo pelo próprio software da Zebra, o Zebra Designer, porem a alteração não é aplicada, e caso a nova palavra seja maior ou menor, dá um erro ao abrir o mesmo pelo software, como mostra as imagens:

- Etiqueta no programa Zebra Designer.

  [image: Etiqueta no Zebra Designer.]
- Etiqueta no Notepad++.

[image: Etiqueta no Notepad++].
- Erro dito acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faria para editar uma etiqueta, criando tags próprias para substituição na etiqueta padrão, em Java?

Comment: Se for para impressora zebra, você teria que usar a linguagem ZPL (ou EPL se o firmware suportar). Tem um site online que vc pode visualizar a etiqueta que está no formato ZPL, talvez te ajude: http://labelary.com/viewer.html 
É possível gerar a etiqeuta no formato ZPL pelo ZebraDesigner também.
Se precisar de mais dicas só perguntar. Boa sorte.

Comment: No caso, como eu faria para salvar em ZPL direto do ZebraDesigner e como eu mandaria esse arquivo ZPL para ser impresso na Zebra usando o USB?

Comment: Estou sem o zebradesigner. Mas se não me engano tem uma opção para imprimir em arquivo em algum lugar.
E esse arquivo vai ter uma linguagem parecida com ZPL.

Para mandar imprimir, vc teria que enviar a String no formato ZPL direto para a impressora. 

Como não estou no trabalho, amanhã respondo para você com mais detalhes.

Boa sorte.

Comment: Bom dia, fico no aguardo de mais detalhes principalmente de como faço para imprimir. Dês de já, te agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para gerar o ZPL do ZebraDesigner:

1. Arquivo -> Imprimir
2. Dentro da janela 'Imprimir' selecionar a opção 'Print To file'
3. Clicar em 'Imprimir'
4. Dar um nome para o arquivo e clique em 'Salvar'
5. O arquivo gerado vai estar no formato ZPL

Para entender melhor cada comando ZPL, tem o link do manual:
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Para enviar a impressão, vc deve enviar o texto que está no arquivo que foi gerado pelos passos acima.

Boa sorte.